# I'm not getting read the property bind

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm trying to make a file component in ReactJS.

I make this way:

```
import React from 'react';

export class InputTxt extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      file: null
    }

    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ 
      file: e.target.files[0] 
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <h1>File Upload</h1>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

But i'm receiving:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

In the line:

`this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)`

Why i'm getting this error?

Comment: There is no such method called `onFormSubmit`.

Comment: please add definition for `onFormSubmit` method

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the method `onFormSubmit`, This should work fine.

```
import React from 'react';

export class InputTxt extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            file: null
        }
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] })
    }

    onFormSubmit() {
      console.log("Form submitted")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <h1>File Upload</h1>
                <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```